# Using Vue and Webpack to create an MPA

Tags: vue.js, multi-page-application

I am trying to learn how to use Vue and Webpack 4 to create a multi-page application.  The main reason for this is that is that the server is not stateless and I need the server to handle routing because of the complexity of permissions and protected routes.

However, I want to use Vue.js to leverage the power of single file components to create reusable and maintainable code.  I understand how to modify my wepack.config.js to set up multiple entry points and I assume that I would just be serving a different bundle that would be injected into a single index.html but there is where the things start becoming unclear to me.

How would I handle this with Vue.js?  Just to be clear, I am not using the Vue CLI and I want to use single file components to design the front end.  A simple project skeleton/boilerplate code would be much appreciated with an emphasis on configuration.

My main entry point (main.js)

```html
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
});
```

webpack.config.js

```html
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader', exclude: '/node_modules'},
      { test: /\.vue$/, use: 'vue-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader']},
      //{ test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/, use: 'file-loader'},
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    hot: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: './src/index.html'}),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    //new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new CopyPlugin([{from: 'src/images', to: 'images'}])
  ]
};
```

Comment: Clearly webpack can generate a different bundle for each specified entry point.  Where I need help is how to make this work with Vue since the default behavior seems to be a SPA

Comment: With vue cli its the pages option

Comment: Sorry but as I stated, I am not using the Vue CLI.

Comment: Yes but vue cli uses webpack - think this might help: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/6323b73260e461c4aeb866fde4231f15d19f9c4e/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js#L348

Comment: Or this https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/bc3e4af3c0532d32ad53602546c2a91187b36948/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/app.js#L151  https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/bc3e4af3c0532d32ad53602546c2a91187b36948/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/app.js#L190